# Set default coordinate precision

Tags: qgis, geojson, precision

Is there a way to set the default coordinate precision to 7 for GeoJSON files in QGIS? This would help me save time when I go to save files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS uses GDAL to write the GeoJSON file. [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html) uses the COORDINATE_PRECISION environment variable. In QGIS that variable is [hardcoded](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d8b0cdacb7928143db068f9816f1b3bd7d4c89da/src/core/qgsvectorfilewriter.cpp#L1076) with the value of 15 (the same as the GDAL default).

If you really want this, you can submit it as a new feature request at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.